# How to use statfs64() in a 32bit program?

Tags: c, linux, glibc

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/statfs.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    struct statfs64 mystatfs64;
    statfs64("/", &mystatfs64);  
    return 0;
}
```

But I get this error:

```
error: storage size of ‘mystatfs64’ isn’t known
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘statfs64’; did you mean ‘statfs’?
```

On the man page it says: The glibc statfs() and fstatfs() wrapper functions transparently deal with the kernel differences.

So I changed my code to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/statfs.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    struct statfs mystatfs;
    statfs("/", &mystatfs);
    return 0;
}
```

It now compiles but sizeof(((struct statfs*)0)->f_blocks) is 4 so I can't handle big file systems.

I also tried to define __USE_LARGEFILE64 and __USE_FILE_OFFSET64 without any success.

Comment: What system are you using? What distribution are you using? What is the glibc version that you are using? What kernel version are you using? What is the exact compilation command you are using? What is the compiler, and compiler version that you are using? Is there no `file:line:` in error messages ?

Comment: @KamilCuk I removed file:line: from the log. I am on debian and compiling like this: gcc main.c -m32. glibc version is 2.28-10+deb10u1

Comment: Re. `((struct statfs*)0)->f_blocks is 4`: you mean `sizeof(((struct statfs*)0)->f_blocks) is 4`, right?  You also need to consider the `f_bsize` field which specifies the size of a block.

Comment: https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/895ef79e04a953cac1493863bcae29ad85657ee1/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/bits/statfs.h#L48 `I also tried to define __USE_LARGEFILE64` Please post how you "tried to define" it. Please try compiling with `-D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1`

Comment: @G.M. f_bsize is not the only field. There are other fields that must have size 8 to handle large file systems.

Comment: @KamilCuk I added these gcc flags -D__USE_LARGEFILE64 -D__USE_FILE_OFFSET64

Comment: The `__USE_*` macros are for `features.h` to define, not you. The option you want is `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`, which will make unadorned `statfs` use 64-bit `off_t`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `__USE_*` macros are for glibc's internal header `features.h` to define, not you.  If you try to define them yourself, they won't work.

You are instead supposed to define macros from a *different* set, called the "feature test macros" or "feature selection macros" and partially specified by POSIX.  The most up-to-date and coherent documentation of the full set of feature test macros understood by glibc is in the Linux manpages: [`feature_test_macros(7)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html).  Note that most of these macros must be defined *before you include any system headers*.

The best way to write the code you're trying to write is to use the `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS` feature test macro to make normal `off_t`, `fsblkcnt_t`, etc. be 64 bits wide:

```
#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/statfs.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    struct statfs mystatfs;
    statfs("/", &mystatfs);
    printf("block count: %"PRIu64"\n", mystatfs.f_blocks);
    return 0;
}
```

If you don't want to add this `#define` to the top of every `.c` file of your program, you may instead be able to add `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` to your compilation options in your Makefile or equivalent (for instance, add it to `CPPFLAGS` if you're using for Make's standard built-in compilation rules).

You also have the option of using `_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE` to gain access to the `xxx64` functions and types, but this is discouraged by the C library maintainers: note what it says about it in the manpage I linked above

> _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE
>
> Expose definitions for the alternative API specified by the LFS (Large File Summit) as a "transitional extension" to the Single UNIX Specification.  (See ⟨https://www.opengroup.org/platform/lfs.html⟩.)  The alternative API consists of a set of new objects (i.e., functions and types) whose names are suffixed with "64" (e.g., `off64_t` versus off_t, `lseek64()` versus `lseek()`, etc.).  **New programs should not employ this macro; instead `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` should be employed.**

(boldface: my emphasis)